# Simple hover zoom thumbnail with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm listing a bunch of items, each with a small thumb and some description alongside.

On mouseover of the thumb, I'd like a slightly larger one to display in front, close on mouseoff. The difference in size won't be much so it will probably just be the same file (thumb will be scaled down)

IS there any simple jquery plugin out there for this?

Comment: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. there is.

Mike Alsup has written a wonderful plugin called **hoverpulse** for this exact requirement.

Demo here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/

Comment: perfect, looks like the ticket.